# How do I draw 2D curves in a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to draw 2D curves in a 3D plot. For example, I have a function

```
F[x_, y_] := (3 x + y(2 + 5 y))/23
```

and want to plot it as shown below:

[image]

I need help with the Mathematica programing.

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions? Also, check out the Linked Questions on the right side of that page.

Comment: Thank you very much @MassDefect,,, It works

Comment: @m_glodberg thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by giving `Plot3D` the right options.

```
With[{ϵ = .05},
  Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0 - ϵ, 3 + ϵ},
    PlotRangePadding -> 0.6,
    PlotStyle -> Transparent,
    BoundaryStyle -> None,
    Boxed -> False,
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
    FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
    FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Dashed],
    AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
    MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
    Mesh -> {Range[0, 3]},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.009]],
    Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

It takes a lot fiddling with the options to get the plot to look like your picture. Also, note the it was necessary to extend the plot range of the y-domain.

[image: plot]