# 3- dimensional plot of 2-dimensional systems of differential equations

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, differential-equations

Let's take this first example of a 2D output:

```
sol = DSolve[
        {y''[t] + y'[t] + y[t] == 3 Sin[t] - 4 Cos[t], 
         y[0] == a, y'[0] == 0},
         y[t], t
      ];
toplot = Table[ sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. a -> i, {i, 0, 3, 0.5}];
Plot[Tooltip[toplot], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

How can I visualize these solutions with a 3-D output like the ones obtainable by ListSurfacePlot3D , the independant variable (a) of my example  being the 3d coordinate? Here I would like to see 7 parallel curves.

Also another example this time for a system of two differential equations:

```
sol = DSolve[
        {x'[t] == x[t]/8 - y[t]  ,
         y'[t] == x[t]   + y[t]/8, 
         x[0] == 0,
         y[0] == 1},
         {x[t], y[t]}, t
      ];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

How can I get a 3D output of these solutions, the 3d coordinate being the variable t (and I expect to get a helix)?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Simplest solution I think would be just using `ParametricPlot3D`. For other techniques please see this questions:

- [**Plotting several functions**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions)
- [**Using ListPointPlot3D to simulate 2D plots moving in time**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159/using-listpointplot3d-to-simulate-2d-plots-moving-in-time)

Now let's look at specifically to your examples and `ParametricPlot3D`.

**Your 1st example** can be simplified a bit:

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[t] + y'[t] + y[t] == 3 Sin[t] - 4 Cos[t],y[0] == a,y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t];
toplot = Table[{t, sol[[1, 1, 2]], a}, {a, 0, 3, 0.5}];

ParametricPlot3D[toplot, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

**And 2nd example** is fine as it is - just add time as 3rd variable to `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], t} /. sol, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Also,

```
ClearAll[sol];
sol[a_?NumericQ] := sol[a] = DSolve[{y''[t] + y'[t] + y[t] == 3 Sin[t] - 4 Cos[t],
                                     y[0] == a, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t];

Plot3D[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol[x]][[1]] /. t -> u, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that you have to `Evaluate[]` before injecting the (valued) variable `u` for the `Solve[]` function to work.

**Edit**

The above plot was done with:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol[x]][[1]] /. t -> u, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 0, 5}, 
       MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
       AxesLabel -> {Style[t, Large, Bold], Style[InputForm[y[0]], Large, Bold]}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], Specularity[.5]], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

Comment: The second solution gives an error message:

Comment: @SigismondKmiecik Works OK here. Try to run it on a fresh kernel, or insert a `ClearAll` before executing, because a previous definition of `sol[]` spoils it

Comment: @SigismondKmiecik Answer updated with `ClearAll`

Comment: It's ok after ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``. Thanks

Comment: With your solution how you can you store in a table the equations  of all the plotted solutions? Is it possible to use the Tooltip function in order to display the specific solutions on the output area? Thanks